# Getting Windows version 23H2 from Win32_OperatingSystem

Tags: windows, visual-c++, wmi

Code:

```
std::map<CString, CString> mapWindowsVersions
{
    { L"22631", L"23H2" },
    { L"22621", L"22H2" },
    { L"22000", L"21H2" },
    { L"19044", L"21H2" },
    { L"19043", L"21H1" },
    { L"19042", L"20H2" },
    { L"19041", L"2004" },
    { L"18363", L"1909" },
    { L"18362", L"1903" },
    { L"17763", L"1809" },
    { L"17134", L"1803" },
    { L"16299", L"1709" }
};
VARIANT vtProp{};
hres = pclsObj->Get(L"BuildNumber", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
strSystemInfo.AppendFormat(L"  Build Number: %s\r\n", mapWindowsVersions[vtProp.bstrVal]);
VariantClear(&vtProp);
```

This works., I gleaned release descriptions from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/windows11-release-information). But is there a built-in way to get this description, eg: 23H2?

Comment: Protip/hint: `ShellAboutW`.

Comment: @Dai I don't understand what I should do with `ShellAboutW`.

Comment: @Dai I don’t see how that is of any use. The docs say it displays an About window. That is not what I am asking.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle The `ShellAboutW` function shows a dialog box which contains the correct string for the current version/build/release of Windows (e.g. "22H2" on my machine). I left it as a hint because I thought you'd see that and then take a look using WinDbg or a disassembler.

Comment: @Dai I already know that the Windows About window displays this info. I have never used disassembler and I don’t see why extracting this information should be that hard really. .

Comment: It's hard because Microsoft is trying to discourage OS version checks entirely. ...though I assume in your case, you're doing it for reporting/inventory reasons?

Comment: I found where the string comes from just now: `Shell32.dll` loads it from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DisplayVersion` - but only for Windows 20H2 or later - for 2004 and earlier, use `CurrentVersion\ReleaseId`.

Comment: @Dai Simply adding useful diagnostic info to my about window in my app.

Comment: ...but I think you're better-off showing _only_ the WMI `Win32_OperatingSystem.BuildNumber` value and ignore the "22H2"-style release names. Especially because that info is already exposed via WMI, but the `DisplayVersion` string is not: you'll need to make a separate registry query for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the answer off-the-top-of-my-head, but I know where to start looking: `winver.exe`.

Here's my *About Windows* dialog, which dutifully displays the "Version 22H2" string you're after:

[image]

- Firing up `winver.exe` in WinDbg or Ghidra or whathaveyou shows that `winver.exe` just calls into `Shell32.dll!ShellAboutW` to do all its actual work.
- ...which in-turn sets-up a Dialog Resource using the (non-exported) function `AboutDlgProc` to drive the *About Windows* dialog.
- ...which calls `_InitAboutDlg` to load the data (strings, text, etc) into the Dialog's labels/placeholders.
- ...which opens the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion` registry key and then extracts values based on some arbitrary *business rules*:

  - Apparently there's a (WinRT? C++/CX?) API called `EnableH2UIVersioning` which controls whether the "22H2"-style release name will be displayed or not. When this is `true` then the "22H2" string comes from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DisplayVersion`, otherwise it uses `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ReleaseId`.
- On my machine, both `DisplayVersion` and `ReleaseId` are present, but `ReleaseId` contains the incorrect/old value of "2009" - which means that `ReleaseId` cannot be trusted if present.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the suggestions in the comments I have come up with the following solution:

```
hres = pclsObj->Get(L"Caption", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
strSystemInfo.AppendFormat(L"  Edition: %s\r\n", vtProp.bstrVal);
VariantClear(&vtProp);

hres = pclsObj->Get(L"Version", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
strSystemInfo.AppendFormat(L"  Version: %s\r\n", vtProp.bstrVal);
VariantClear(&vtProp);

hres = pclsObj->Get(L"BuildNumber", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
strSystemInfo.AppendFormat(L"  Version Build Number: %s\r\n", vtProp.bstrVal);

CSettingsStore store(true, true);
if (store.Open(L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion"))
{
    CString strDisplayVersion;
    const auto buildNumber = _ttoi(CString(vtProp.bstrVal));
    if (buildNumber > 19041)
    {
        if (store.Read(L"DisplayVersion", strDisplayVersion))
        {
            strSystemInfo.AppendFormat(L"  Version Codename: %s\r\n", strDisplayVersion);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (store.Read(L"ReleaseId", strDisplayVersion))
        {
            strSystemInfo.AppendFormat(L"  Version Codename: %s\r\n", strDisplayVersion);
        }
    }
}
VariantClear(&vtProp);
```

Which displays the following output on my About window:

```
Edition: Microsoft Windows 11 Home
Version: 10.0.22631
Version Build Number: 22631
Version Codename: 23H2
```

Comment: That seems to be missing something. before `CSettingsStore`..., vtProp gets cleared, and not assigned or changed in any way before you try to extract the build number again

Comment: @peterchen I updated the code. I should clear it afterwards.

Comment: I'm not familiar with MFC's Registry/`CSettingsStore` type - can you explain how it would handle missing registry keys/values, or values with unexpected types (e.g. string vs. dword)?

Comment: Seeing `_ttoi()` sent a shiver down my spine. Seeming as your code is now specifically written for Windows 10 there is zero reason to support MBCS or ANSI/OEM like we're still running Windows 95 - please just let `TCHAR.h` die.

Comment: @Dai `CSettingStore`: learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/… It returns `false` if the key doesn’t open. Similarly `Read` returns `true` if the value exists. As for `_ttoi` it is just that my app is 20 years strong. I always use the t macros I guess. It won’t run on pre windows 10 as you say.

Comment: @Dai Proper link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/csettingsstore-class?view=msvc-170